# Managed code by leveraging EWS for getting meetings scheduled in a particular room

Tags: .net, outlook, exchangewebservices

I have a requirement to get meetings scheduled in a particular room (outlook meetings) and prepare a HTML based report so that it can printed and pasted in rooms. I am writing outlook addin for this. I did look for EWS API, but did not find direct web method to get the data that i need. Any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible - though you have to combine this http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2007/04/webservice-to-find-room-and-equipment.html and this http://gsexdev.blogspot.com/2007/05/resource-mailbox-availability-web-page.html .

BEWARE - there are some security/permission settings to deal with...